# How to create custom date objects in PHP and compare them?

Tags: php, date, variables, object, compare

How can I create date object using custom variables? 


I have following variables. Then I want to create 2 different date objects in PHP and compare them if one of them is earlier than it.

```
$day = 22;
$month = 2;
$year = 2014;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of PHP 5.2.2, DateTime objects can be compared using comparison operators. <-- from docs
var_dump($date1 == $date2);
var_dump($date1 < $date2);
var_dump($date1 > $date2);

create the dates with date_create (or use OO style).
$date1 = date_create('formatted_date using $y,$m,$d') <-- see docs

done

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be more precise about hours, minutes and even seconds... you should try this:

```
if(mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d,$y) > mktime(0,0,0,$m2,$d2,$y2) {
 // do something
}
```

follow this manual for more details on [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) function: